# Bokeh Server Plot - How to make new values appear in the center with a fixed axis range

Tags: bokeh, bokehjs

I want to create a plot that shows the live metering data I am getting from an electricity meter.

I already figured out how to have a plot in bokeh, that updates every x seconds with new values, but now I want to have the new values always be at a fixed point in the plot, while the range of the axis does not increase.
I fixed the range by adding x_range=[0, 10] to the figure, however that plot is running out of the screen and I have to manually follow it.
How do I change it so it follows it automatically?

Is that even possible in bokeh or should I be using something different for my project?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a default `DataRange1d` range (i.e. do *not* set the range to a fixed interval) and then set the [`follow`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/ranges.html?highlight=follow#bokeh.models.ranges.DataRange1d.follow) property on the range. You can also set `follow_interval` to specify how far back the range should trail the latests data.

```py
p.x_range.follow = "end"
p.x_range.follow_interval = 100
```

For a complete demonstration see the [OHLC ticker example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/branch-2.2/examples/app/ohlc/).

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you by any chance know how I can connect to my bokeh server through another browser on a different machine in the same network?

Comment: If you are just connecting to the Bokeh server directly then it should just work to use the ip address. If you have a hostname set up or are embedding the bokeh server in some other site you will need to start the bokeh server with the `--allow-websocket-orgin` option to allow connections from those origins. If there are still issues, a new topic with debug information (browser js logs, server console logs) is appropriate.

Comment: So I tried just starting the server on my laptop through command line, then found out my IP via a google search and then tried to enter the IP:5006/BokehServer (which is my script name) on my phone, however that just gave me the error: Cannot open page because it could not connect to the server.

Comment: Please open a separate new question, here or on the project Discourse https://discourse.bokeh.org/